# Celery with Flask and UWSGI

Tags: python-3.x, flask, celery, uwsgi

I have a simple application flask with a simple celery task:

```
from flask import Flask
from celery import Celery


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'] = 'redis://localhost:6379'
app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'] = 'redis://localhost:6379'

celery = Celery(app.name, broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
celery.conf.update(app.config)

@celery.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y


@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def test_func():
   res = add.delay(4,5)
   while not res.ready():
      pass
   data = res.get()
   return str(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':

   app.run(host='0.0.0.0',debug=True)
```

When I try to use your exemple with uwsgi but I encounter almost the same error than you.
First, I run it simply with python:

`python app.py`

and the broker with the following command:

`celery -A app.celery worker -l info`

Everything is working perfectly. Now I try to launch the flask application with uwsgi.

```
[uwsgi]
mount = /=/home/admin/flask-celery/app.py
callable = app
virtualenv = /home/admin/flask-celery/.venv
socket = :3031
master = true 
processes = 2
threads = 4
http = :9000
```

But when I go on my route, I encounter the following error:

`celery.exceptions.NotRegistered: 'uwsgi_file__home_admin_flask-celery_app.add'`

Answer (score 0):

Pleas take a look at this:https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/AttachingDaemons.html

Although the following configuration does not exactly match your environment, I hope this could help.

```
[uwsgi]
base = /home/project
chdir = %(base)
module = app
pythonpath = %(base)
virtualenv = %(base)/venv
wsgi-file = %(base)/app.py
master = true
smart-attach-daemon = %(base)/tmp/celery.pid %(virtualenv)/bin/celery -A %(module).celery  worker --pidfile=%(base)/tmp/celery.pid
socket = %(base)/socket.sock
chmod-socket = 777
processes = 4
threads = 4
logto = %(base)/log/%n.log
stats = 127.0.0.1:9191
```

Answer (score -1):

Try specifying task name explicitly, for example like this:

```
@celery.task(name='app.celery.add')
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

To ensure changes takes effect, restart celery worker after you made changes and cleanup all `*.pyc` files with `find . -name '*.pyc' -delete`